# SQL Query for Opening Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a basic Book Keeping System using SQL Server.

1. tbl_opening_balance
2. tbl_main_transaction
3. tbl_sub_transaction

`tbl_opening_balance` consists of opening balance of an Account taken before the Database takes over of recording the Transaction. `tbl_opening_balance` stores the opening balance of the Third Level Chart of Account. `tbl_main_transaction` and `tbl_sub_transactions` records Voucher Entries against the fourth level Chart of Account. There are four level chart of Accounts stored separately in their own tables. All these tables are related to each other through foreign keys.

I wish I could sqlfiddle it, however it keeps on giving me a create script error.

Now to my problem.

The Ledger is generally required for the Third Level Chart of Account And for a Certain Period. So what i want basically is.

1. Select the Account (Third Level) for which the Ledger is to be made.
2. Select the Opening Balance from `tbl_opening_balance`
3. Find the Related Transactions in `tbl_sub_transaction`
4. Sum All the Debits and Credits from the selected records in `tbl_sub_transactions` BEFORE the Period for which the Ledger is created
5. Add or Subtract Debit and Credit Entries from value returned from `tbl_opening_balance`. This should return the Opening Balance for the Period
6. List the transaction records from `tbl_sub_transaction` and for each transaction add/subtract the opening balance, which should give the closing balance at the end of the ledger

Here is the structure of the tables (SqlFiddle keeps on giving me create script error).

https://codeshare.io/ro3QC

```
select debit,credit,TOB.opening_credit, TOB.opening_debit from       tbl_sub_transactions ST
INNER JOIN head3 ON head3.code=head3_code
INNER JOIN head2 on head2.code=head3.parent_code
INNER JOIN tbl_opening_balance TOB on TOB.account_code=head2.code
INNER JOIN tbl_main_transactions MT on MT.voucher_no=ST.voucher_no
WHERE head3_code='XXXXX' AND date_of_trans < '1/1/2016'
```

;

This returns the Related Debit and Credit entries in tbl_sub_transaction TABLE and the corresponding opening_credit and opening debit enteries for a particular Level 3 Chart of Account Before a Particular Date .

This query returns the detail records of transactions in a given period.

```
select ST.voucher_no, ST.head3_code, credit, debit  from  tbl_sub_transactions ST 
INNER JOIN tbl_main_transactions MT on MT.voucher_no=ST.voucher_no

WHERE date_of_trans BETWEEN '2/1/2016' AND '11/5/2016'
```

;

The above query returns the Detailed Records Required. 
My Problem is to subtract/add the opening_credit or opening_debit enteries respectively from each debit records from each detailed record.
Any suggestions?

Comment: paste the sqlfiddle here ,so that one can rectify error and use it,also please paste the expected resuly

Comment: The structure is at https://codeshare.io/ro3QC

Comment: can you post some sample data & expected result ? also please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Without thoroughly reading the whole question, the first thing that comes to mind - I would not have a separate `tbl_opening_balance` table at all. I would simply add a transaction that carries the required amount onto the account, i.e. initialises an account with some balance.

Comment: Transaction and opening balance belong to seperate level in Chart of accounts